# JS: Catch network error and return default response data

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I am developing an app that uses promises to communicate with an remote API. This app needs to be able to work offline seamlessly, so I need to handle network errors. Since I can define some default data upfront that is good enough to keep the app functioning. My approach is to catch the error and return a new promise loaded with the default data:

**API.js**

```
function getDataFromAPI(id) {
  return axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      // Only return fake data in cases of connection issues
      if (error.message == 'Network error') {
          const fakeResponse = {myDefaultData: 'default data all over the place'};
          // receiving function expects data in promise-form
          return Promise.resolve(fakeResponse);          
      }    
    });
}
```

**Action.js using the API**

```
needSomeData = () => {
    api.getDataFromAPI().then((response) => {
         // Data is processed/used here
    }));
```

The code sample works but I am not sure if this is a good/clean approach? Would it be better to handle this in a service worker? Or should I use an entirely different way to approach the issue?

Comment: I think you mean `Promise.resolve(fakeResponse)`

Comment: You are right, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you can clean it a little bit more.

since any return from `.catch` consider the value of the next `resolved` promise. you do not need to return `Promise.resolve(value)` return `value` are enough

```
function getDataFromAPI(id) {
   return axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/${id}`)
         .then(response => response.data)
         .catch((error) => {
            // Only return fake data in cases of connection issues
            if (error.message == 'Network error') {
               return {
                  myDefaultData: 'default data all over the place'
               };
            else {
               return 'return something or throw new exception' 
            }    
          });
}
```

So for whom that want to know exactly how `Promise` algorithm behave
[Promises/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/)

In fact I find It very interesting

Comment: Thanks for the simplification. Can you say something more about the general approach? Is it considered a misuse of .catch to return a replacement value? And do you think it is benefitial to address the matter in a service worker/on the network level or directly in the API requesting code (I am probably a bit over-concerned with using bad practises...)

Comment: you are in the right place to concerened about good/bad practice :) . 

so. no, it is good idea to return replacement value from `.catch` it's just like `try{}catch(e){}` in synchronous code. when the job of the `catch(e)` is catch the error so the whale application not crash.